# Highcharts: Stop the circle marker from shrinking in size on mouseover

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I am making bubble charts using this workaround suggested by highcharts.
http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/994151-bubble-chart

In the link provided for sample bubble chart: 
http://highcharts.com/cases/bubble.htm

How do I stop the circle marker from shrinking in size on mouseover? I want the circles to remain as is and show tooltip.

I fiddled around for this one but could not find the solution.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the hover option to **false**

```
 plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
         marker: {
            radius: 5,
            states: {
               hover: {
                  **enabled: false,**
                  lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
               }
            }
         },
.....
```